# Using for loop to make predictions grouped by

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, scikit-learn, regression

I have this time series  dataframe which looks like this:

```
Employee_ID  Age     Start_Date           End_Date          Profits
   111       43   01/07/2020 9:00       30/07/2020 9:04     7772.14
   111       43   01/08/2020 9:00       30/08/2020 9:04     4352.46
   111       43   01/09/2020 9:00       30/09/2020 9:00     4532.66
   222       55   01/07/2020 9:00       30/07/2020 9:04     5643.73
   222       55   01/08/2020 9:00       30/08/2020 9:00     7685.15
   222       55   01/09/2020 9:00       01/09/2020 9:00     4573.53
```

I created a linear regression model to predict the profits in a specific date. I selected July and August as a training set and September as a test set. My code looks like is:

```
# Load the dataset
df['Start_Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Start_Date'], dayfirst=True)
df=df.sort_values(by='Start_Date',ascending=True)
df = df.set_index(df['Start_Date'])
df = df.sort_index()
del df["Start_Date"]

# create train test partition
my_train = df['2020-07-01':'2020-08-30']
my_test  =  df['2020-09-01':'2020-09-30']

X_train = deepcopy(my_train)
X_test = deepcopy(my_test)
y_train = X_train.Profits
y_test = X_test.Profits

del X_train["Profits"]
del X_test["Profits"]

# Train and fit the model
my_regressor = LinearRegression()
my_regressor.fit(X_train, y_train)

# Make prediction
y_pred = my_regressor.predict(X_test)

# Evaluate the model
#print('Mean Absolute Error:', metrics.mean_absolute_error(y_test, y_pred))
print('Mean Absolute Error:', '{:.2f}'.format(metrics.mean_absolute_error(y_test, y_pred)))
```

The code worked good with me with no errors, but my question is that I want to make the prediction grouped by Employee_ID. In other words, I want to show the the MAE error for each Employee. Here I could use the for loop.

The output should looks like this:

```
Mean Absolute Error for Employee 111 is : 24.09
Mean Absolute Error for Employee 222 is : 12.09
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can do like:

```
# add predictions to test data
X_test['score'] = metrics.mean_absolute_error(y_test, y_pred)

# calculate agg score metrics for group
X_test.groupby('Employee_ID')['score'].mean()
```